# Using pipe operation in R properly

Tags: r, dplyr

I was examining below code

```
library(dplyr)
DF = data.frame('A' = 1:3, 'B' =2:4)
Condition = 'A'
fn1 = function(x) x + 3
fn2 = function(x) x + 5
DF %>% mutate('aa' = 3:5) %>%
{if (Condition == 'A') {
bb = . %>% mutate('A1' = fn1(A), 'B1' = fn1(B)) 
bb
} else {
bb = . %>% mutate('A1' = fn2(A), 'B1' = fn2(B)) 
bb
}   
}
```

Basically, I have 2 similar functions `fn1` and `fn2`. Now based on some condition, I want to use one of these functions.

Above implementation is throwing below error -

```
Functional sequence with the following components:

 1. mutate(., A1 = fn1(A), B1 = fn1(B))

Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

Can you please help be how to properly write the pipe sequence to execute above code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `across` within `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
   mutate(aa = 3:5, across(c(A, B), ~  if(Condition == 'A') fn1(.) 
         else fn2(.), .names = "{.col}1"))
```

-output

```
  A B aa A1 B1
1 1 2  3  4  5
2 2 3  4  5  6
3 3 4  5  6  7
```

---

Also, an option is to get the functions in a `list` and convert the logical vector to numeric index for subsetting

```
DF %>% 
   mutate(aa = 3:5, 
   across(c(A, B), ~  list(fn2, fn1)[[1 + (Condition == 'A')]](.), 
         .names = "{.col}1"))
```

-output

```
 A B aa A1 B1
1 1 2  3  4  5
2 2 3  4  5  6
3 3 4  5  6  7
```

---

Based on the comments, if we need a custom name for the new columns, create a named vector and replace with `str_replace_all`

```
library(stringr)
nm1 <- setNames(c("XXX", "YYY"), names(DF)[1:2])
DF %>% 
   mutate(aa = 3:5, 
   across(c(A, B), ~  list(fn2, fn1)[[1 + (Condition == 'A')]](.), 
         .names = "{str_replace_all(.col, nm1)}"))
  A B aa XXX YYY
1 1 2  3   4   5
2 2 3  4   5   6
3 3 4  5   6   7
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain `"{.col}1"`?

Comment: @Bogaso. If you don't change the original column name, then the original columns i.e. A, B, gets updated.  So, we change it in `.names` with new names by appending 1 at the end. `.col` gives the column name of the looped columns

Comment: Thanks. What I need to do if I want custom names for new columns? I tried with `.names = c("XXX", "YYY")` but getting error

Comment: @Bogaso You can't use multiple vector elements in `.names` An option can be to use `str_replace_all` with a named vector or may use `rename_with` after the mutate step

Comment: @Bogaso updated the post.  Please check if that helsps

Comment: Thank is perfect!!

Comment: one more question. How can I use the function if that function has multiple arguments? e.g. let say my functions are `fn1 = function(x, y = 2) x + 3^y` and `fn2 = function(x, y = 2) x + 5^y`? How can I pass the second argument?

Comment: @Bogaso You may either use `if/else if/else` or create as a list and then change the condition to return an index i.e. 1, 2, 3 instead of TRUE/FALSE depends on your Condition value.  Or another option is create a switch function with different values for 'Condition' and get the relevant function based on the input Condition

Comment: @Bogaso sorry, I was thinking that you have multiple functions i.e .> 2.  If you have multiple arguments, what will be 'y' column

Comment: @Bogaso let's say you have a 'C' column that corresponds to 'y', then `DF %>% 
   mutate(aa = 3:5, 
   across(c(A, B), ~  list(fn2, fn1)[[1 + (Condition == 'A')]](., y = Z), 
         .names = "{str_replace_all(.col, nm1)}"))`